# How to fingerprint Windows 10 reliably?

Tags: windows, penetration-test, nmap, fingerprinting

Recently, I have been practicing penetration testing and I have come to a standstill when trying to fingerprint the OS for a Windows 10 target with nmap.

For the most part, I'm not able to identify the machine as Windows 10. The best guess nmap offers is "Windows". I've also tried p0f and xprobe2, with similar results.

How can I reliably fingerprint a Windows 10 target over the network, from a blackbox perspective?

Comment: OS fingerprinting is "messy" and getting a reliable, but getting the right family of operating system is a good start. Are you interested in solutions purely based on nmap or other tools as well?

Comment: @MechMK1, I open to other tools as well.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 and what version of Nmap? If your version of Nmap predates the release of Windows 10 (e.g. Windows 10 1809 was released after Nmap 7.70), then the fingerprint will not be present.

Comment: For Nmap, I'm using version 7.70 and Windows 10 Pro Version 1803. 
What I get is Server 2008 SP1 or Server 2008 R2 (85%)

Comment: You might consider also use the tool p0f (http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) for fingerprint, is a passive analysis tool that could help you on the identification.